# Performance tuning via sysctl, what is the difference between setting net.core.rmem_default (r/w) / net.ipv4.tcp_mem / net.ipv4.udp_mem

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, udp, sysctl

What is the difference between setting read/write mem default via net/core and setting the protocol min/max/default net/ipv4 in sysctl?

Detailed explanation or resource request

> net.core.wmem_default 
>   net.core.rmem_default 
>   net.ipv4.tcp_mem 
>   net.ipv4.udp_mem

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/net.txt

net.ipv4.tcp_mem and net.ipv4.udp_mem limit total kernel memory for tcp and udp respectively, where as others control per socket buffer space